# How to count keywords in a text box using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using `string.split(",")` to count keywords, but it is actually counting commas instead of keywords.

for example:

`word1, word2,`

is actually 2 keywords but using `string.split(",")` I receive 3 count.

Is there any logic I can put, that if there is nothing written after comma then don't count.

I tried this

```
function KeywordCountToUse(inputToCheckId) {
    var content = $('#' + inputToCheckId).val();
    var words = content.split(",");
    return words.length;
}
```

Comment: just use arrays let words=[word1,word2];
console.log(words.length())

Comment: @UmairFarooq did you miss the part about *"in a text box"*?

Comment: Please share more details, like sample input, the expected output, and the code you are using. Also, is this really a problem related to HTML or jQuery?

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry

Comment: `string.split(",").filter(Boolean)`

Comment: `'word1, word2,'.split(',') ` will split content delimited by commas.. so the resulting array will contain 3 items because you have the last comma delimiting an empty string. By the way `Array.length` is not a function

Comment: Just "trim" the `,`: `s = s.replace(/[,\s]+$/, "").split(",")`

Comment: "I tried this" - and what's the problem with the given snippet?

Comment: @NicoHaase exactly what's described in the question :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All Three Cases Shown.In the last one i am checking if the string is empty or not and filtering them

```js
let string = "word1,word2,word3";
let count = string.split(",").length;
console.log("Prints three:",count);

let string2 = "word1,word2,";
let count2 = string2.split(",").length;
console.log("Also Prints three:",count2);


let string3 = "word1,word2,";
let substrings = string3.split(",");
let count3 = substrings.filter(str => str !== "").length;
console.log(count3);
```

Comment: This is helping but, whenever i press spacebar its count change to 3, I want if user write something then count

Comment: should the words count based on ","commas or spaces?and how are getting the value from the user

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly

Comment: Thank you for your concern :). I found my solution with this
let count = str.trim().split(',').filter(i=>i).length;